# Unable to get the value on drop downlist selected value for kendo dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

Basically what i want to achieve is i have a button called New and dropdownlist called const. Currently the dropdownlist populate correctly from the database. What i have the problem now is when i select the dropdowlist value and click new button it currently does not select the selected value.

//View

```
    <input id="btnNewOpt" type="button" value="New" style="width:50px"/>

     @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "font-size:12px; width:255px" })
          .Name("const")
          .DataTextField("OptName")
          .DataValueField("OptID")
          .OptionLabel("Select option name")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetTypeStatus", "Index");
              });
          })

       )


    $(document).ready(function () {

          $('#btnNewOpt').click(function (e)
          {
              var dropdownlist = $("#const").data("kendoDropDownList");

          }

        });

//controller:
  public JsonResult GetTypeStatus()
        {
            var consumerStatus = new HEntities();

            return Json(consumerStatus.vwCStatus.Select(c => new { OptID = c.OptID, OptName = c.OptName, OptiTypeID = c.OptiTypeID })
                .OrderBy(c => c.OptName), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add select() add it work now

// create your kendo dropdown and reference to it

```
var mydropdown = $("#const").data("kendoDropDownList").select();   

// onclick ... get the value from kendo dropdown
$('#btnNewOpt').click(function (e){
 var selectedValue = mydropdown.value();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't executed correctly: .value() is not found on mydropdown. Bobby_D_'s solution obtains the correct value for me.

Answer (score 4):

Define your kendo dropdown in global scope and then in your click handle access the selected value by calling value().

```
 // create your kendo dropdown and reference to it
var mydropdown = $("#const").data("kendoDropDownList");   

// onclick ... get the value from kendo dropdown
$('#btnNewOpt').click(function (e){
 var selectedValue = mydropdown.value();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bobby.but it still keep getting the value = 1, event if you select the different value in the dropdownlist

Comment: I'm not sure why 'var mydropdown' is defined outside the handler. It doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 2):

Try these options out.

1)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

          $('#btnNewOpt').click(function (e)
          {
              var dropdownlist = $("#const").data("kendoDropDownList").value.toString();

          }

        });
```

2)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                  $('#btnNewOpt').click(function (e)
                  {

                   var dropdownlist = $("#const").data("kendoDropDownList")[0].form.const.value;

                  }

                });
```

3)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                      $('#btnNewOpt').click(function (e)
                      {
                        var dropdownlist = $("#const").val();            
                      }

                    });
```